# where the real time audio data is stored in mobile?

Tags: audio-recording

we want to route the call to ip network instead of GSM network. for that purpose first we are connecting our mobile phone to a PC through bluetooth. So we want to transfer the real time audio data to that PC over bluetooth. Could you please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you can *trick* the mobile phone to function as a [bluetooth headeset [profile]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) -- which I *doubt* any phones would support because phones are, well, the *consumers* of such headset devices -- then you could use it like any other "headset" device. (It would be much more feasible to just purchase a headset or plug in a microphone.)

As far as "where the real time audio data is stored?" -- well, that *just won't go anywhere*. The "data" (perhaps already in an encoded/delta form) is *briefly* (like milliseconds!) "stored" in a few small buffers / integrated circuits in the radio circuitry. This circuity will vary based upon phone/radio module used and is *not accessible* from a PC.

Happy doing productive things.